# Using PowerShell, read multiple known file names, append text of all files, create and write to one output file

Tags: powershell

I have five .sql files and know the name of each file. For this example, call them one.sql, two.sql, three.sql, four.sql and five.sql. I want to append the text of all files and create one file called master.sql. How do I do this in PowerShell? Feel free to post multiple answers to this problem because I am sure there are several ways to do this.

My attempt does not work and creates a file with several hundred thousand lines.

```
PS C:\sql> get-content '.\one.sql' | get-content '.\two.sql' | get-content '.\three.sql' | get-content '.\four.sql' | get-content '.\five.sql' | out-file -encoding UNICODE master.sql
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Get-Content one.sql,two.sql,three.sql,four.sql,five.sql > master.sql
```

Note that `>` is equivalent to `Out-File -Encoding Unicode`.  I only tend to use Out-File when I need to specify a different encoding.

Comment: Speed it up by specifying the `-Delimiter ([char]0)` (set the delimiter to some character that's not in the file, eg: the null char, or at least use `-ReadCount 0`) for Get-Content, thus reading (and writing) whole files at once instead of line-by-line

Comment: @Jaykul Or in PowerShell V3 use `Get-Content -Raw`.

Answer (score 5):

There are some good answers here but if you have a whole lot of files and maybe you don't know all of the names this is what I came up with:

```
$vara = get-childitem -name "path"

$varb = foreach ($a in $vara) {gc "path\$a"}
```

example

```
$vara = get-childitem -name "c:\users\test"

$varb = foreach ($a in $vara) {gc "c:\users\test\$a"}
```

You can obviously pipe this directly into `| add-content` or whatever but I like to capture in variables so I can manipulate later on.

Answer (score 1):

See if this works better

get-childitem "one.sql","two.sql","three.sql","four.sql","five.sql" | get-content | out-file -encoding UNICODE master.sql

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
Get-Content .\one.sql,.\two.sql,.\three.sql,.\four.sql,.\five.sql | Set-Content .\master.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed something similar, Chris Berry's post helped, but I think this is more efficient:

```
gci -name "*PathToFiles*" | gc > master.sql
```

The first part `gci -name "*PathToFiles*"` gets you your file list. This can be done with wildcards to just get your .sql files i.e. `gci -name "\\share\folder\*.sql"`

Then pipes to Get-Content and redirects the output to your master.sql file. As noted by Kieth Hill, you can use Out-File in place of > to better control your output if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think logical way of solving this is to use Add-Content

```
$files = Get-ChildItem '.\one.sql', '.\two.sql', '.\three.sql', '.\four.sql', '.\five.sql'
$files | foreach { Get-Content $_ | Add-Content '.\master.sql' -encoding UNICODE }
```

hovewer Get-Content is usually very slow when reading multiple very large files. If its your case this article could help: http://keithhill.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!5A8D2641E0963A97!756.entry

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do concatenate sql files from the Sql folder:

```
# Set the current location of the script to use relative path
Set-Location $PSScriptRoot

# Concatenate all the sql files
$concatSql = Get-Content -Path .\Sql\*.sql

# Write/overwrite sql to single file
Add-Content -Path concatFile.sql -Value $concatSql
```